# How to declare the put method of Hash Table?

Tags: hashtable

I don´t know how to resolve this error about the declaration of put method...

```
private Hashtable<Acronimo, Acronimo> lista;

public Dicionario() {
    lista = new Hashtable<Acronimo, Acronimo>();
}

//adiciona

public boolean juntaAcronimo(Acronimo aAcronimo) {
    if( lista != null) {
        return lista.put(aAcronimo.getChave(), aAcronimo);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The method put(Acronimo, Acronimo) in the type Hashtable is not applicable for the arguments (String, Acronimo)

Answer (score 0):

You have used invalid [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) in the `lista` field declaration, it should be:

```
private Hashtable<String, Acronimo> lista;
```

Consider using a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of `Hashtable`. `Hashtable` is an old class from early Java version and due to backward compatibility it's needlessly synchronized.

```
private Map<String, Acronimo> lista = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `aAcronimo.getChave()` returns `String` while you defined your hashtable as `<Acronimo, Acronimo>` so all you have to do is to change this:

```
private Hashtable<String, Acronimo> lista;
```